# How can I see the entity data of an existing item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I'm using [Thaumcraft](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1292130-thaumcraft-5-0-3-updated-2015-11-9), which adds a bunch of new items. One in particular (research note) is useless without the correct NBT tags. Unfortunately, I don't know what the correct NBT tags look like.

How can I see the entity data of an existing item so that I can find the NBT tags I need?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**In 1.13+**, you can hold the item in your hand and type:

```
/data get entity @s SelectedItem
```

[image: Item data in chat for new versions]

You can [copy this from the output log](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292447/how-to-copy-text-from-chat/292466#292466), if you want to avoid retyping it all.

The corresponding `/give` command would be:

```
/give @s minecraft:enchanted_book{StoredEnchantments:[{lvl:1s,id:"minecraft:protection"}]}
```

(note how the extra NBT gets automatically placed inside the `tag` tag)

---

**In 1.8 to 1.12**, you'll need to throw down the item in front of you and then type:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Item,r=3] {}
```

In chat you'll see all of the data of the item  entity, which includes stuff like its motion and age. For the item itself, look at the tags inside the `Item:` compound tag, highlighted in green below:

[image: Item data in chat for old versions]

---

Alternatively, you can use an external program such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) to open up the world, then your player's inventory, then find the item you want to look at the tags of.

Comment: Just note that Thaumcraft is not updated for 1.8 yet i believe

Comment: @ModDL I've been playing 5.0.3, which is for 1.8.

Comment: If you want to copy the tags, just put `/entitydata` command in command block with output tracking on and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, as of ItemsAdder `3.4.1-r4`, the following command should return entity data, including NBT, of an item currently being held by a player `Player1`:

```
/data get entity @p[name=Player1] SelectedItem
```

If it does not output anything in-game, you might want to try it on the server console.

---

In case of [ItemsAdder](https://spigotmc.org/resources/73355), [CustomModelData](https://mcmodels.net/how-to-tutorials/resource-pack-tutorials/what-is-custommodeldata-2) should be possible to obtain via `/iacustommodeldata <namespace>:<item>` (as in `items.yml` of the corresponding resource pack). The range of the value ItemsAdder sets to auto-generated items is defined in the plugin's `config.yml` (as of `v3.4.1-r4`).

Related: https://itemsadder.devs.beer/plugin-usage/commands

Comment: This is a duplicate of SirBenet's answer.

Comment: @pppery, thank you for the minus! ^^ I am sorry, but I would not say so. Their answer and `@s` didn't work for me. It also did not work in-game with no output or error, but only the mentioned one and in the server console (without prefix `/` ).