# How Do I Get The NBT Data a Specific Block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to get the NBT data of a block as a string e.g. The NBT data of a chest. I know that this is possible as I had to do it a year or so ago for a key to a house I had built.

Comment: Do you want to get the NBT data and store it as a string somehow, or just see it in chat?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `/blockdata` command to see tile entity data. Providing no input will show the current state of that data. For instance, stand on top of a chest and run the following:

```
/blockdata ~ ~-1 ~ {}
```

Answer (score 1):

This way isn't very efficient, but it's how I have always done it (and I don't know another way):

1. Look at the chest, hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, and press your pick block button (configurable in options). This should give you a chest item with identical NBT data.
2. Place a command block down anywhere that doesn't have armor stands adjacent to it (including diagonally)
3. Run the command using the command block:

   ```
   /summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {ShowArms:1}
   ```
4. Then put the chest item in the hand of the armor stand, then run this command in the command block:

   ```
   /entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand,c=1] {}
   ```
5. You can then go to the output of the command block, look for the `Items` tag and copy the text within the following '['. Alternatively, you can copy the whole output, paste it in a text editor, press <kbd>ctrl + F</kbd>, and search for the tag.

An example of what I would copy is:

```
Items:[0:{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:sandstone",Count:1b,Damage:0s}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, as of ItemsAdder `3.4.1-r4`, the following command should return entity data, including NBT, of an item currently being held by a player `Player1`:

```
/data get entity @p[name=Player1] SelectedItem
```

If it does not output anything in-game, you might want to try it on the server console.

---

Related: [How can I see the entity data of an existing item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248001/how-can-i-see-the-entity-data-of-an-existing-item/402200#402200)