# How to copy text from chat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What I am trying to do is copy text from the Minecraft chat that has been posted by someone else, as far as my knowledge goes I don't know if this is possible.  I am trying to copy a long command and this could be very useful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**If using the newest launcher:**

You can enable the game log from the launcher settings:

[image: New launcher settings]

Then, when you're playing, the game log will open and display, among other things, chat from players:

[image: New chat]

From there, you are able to copy and paste out anything that was said.

---

**If using the older Java launcher:**

You can change your profile settings to keep the launcher open when you play the game:

[image: Old launcher settings]

Then, when you're playing, the game launcher will display in the `Game Output` tab, among other things, chat from players:

[image: Old chat]

From there, you are able to copy and paste out anything that was said.

Comment: Notice that you need to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C<kbd> to copy text from the console, if you press right mouse button you can only copy all text

Answer (score 4):

The only way to interact with chat in vanilla minecraft is when it has hoverEvent or clickEvent set, which can only be achieved with commands.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the most you can do in Vanilla Minecraft is take a screenshot and cut out the chat message.

If you're willing to use mods, there are more various mods you can use. I'd recommend the **[ChatLog mod](http://www.9minecraft.net/chatlog-mod/)**. This mod allows you to:

> - **Saves all chat, automatically, to a folder called “chatlogs” in .minecraft**
> - Only one class file
> - Saves colors!
> - Several color themes to select from
> - Doesn’t send anything to the server, meaning it won’t say anything in your place
> - **You can play on vanilla servers**
> - Compatible with most other mods
> - **Does not require ModLoader or Forge**
> - **All messages are timestamped**
> - Configuration file (.minecraftconfigChatLog.properties)
> - Compatible with 1.6.4, 1.7.x, 1.8, 1.8.1; **the 1.8 versions are said to be compatible with newer versions of Minecraft**<sup>1</sup>
>
> New in version 2.0 (currently only Forge):
>
> - Type `//cl` in-game for help
> - Filter messages using RegEx
> - Turn logging on or off completely

<sup>From 9minecraft.net, text edited</sup>

---

You don't need forge to use this mod, but the installation gets more complicated without it. The linked page above has got a guide on how to install the mod without Forge, and here is how to do it with forge:

- Download and install Minecraft Forge
- Download ChatLog Mod ([1.8 (and higher?) download link](https://varden.info/download.php?sid=1&v=1.3.8.40))
- Browse to `.minecraft/bin` and open your `minecraft.jar` with an archive manager, eg. 7zip, Winrar, Archive Manager (Linux), etc.
- Delete the META-INF folder
- Drag ChatLog Mod jar file into your minecraft.jar

---

<sup>1</sup>: I don't know the truthfullness of this information as I haven't tested this, just got it online. Please forgive me if it's false.